# Can a DataGridView bound to a LINQ to Objects query be edited?

Tags: datagridview

This is driving me up the nearest wall.  I have a `List<MyClass>` object with several entries (let's call it MyList), and I have a `DataGridView` control.  I can set the DataSource property of the control to MyList.  I get all of the elements of in MyList, with separate columns for each member of the MyClass object, very nicely. If I change any of the members, I can then use the debugger to look at MyList and see the changed values.

But suppose MyList has 10,000 entries, and I only want to look at 10 of them.  I can use LINQ to Objects to filter the list something like this:

```
query = from myObect 
in MyList 
where SomeField == SomeGoodValue select new {myObject.SomeMember};
MyDataGridView.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

This displays the data I want (well, in this case it selects one member of each object), but the data can no longer be edited.

Is there some way to get a filtered list into a `DataGridView`, and have the view control be editable?  I am gathering that the use of the anonymous type generated by the `new` block makes this impossible.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a 100% sure but I believe if you want your cells to be editable you can unbind your source from the grid and rebind it later. It is not ideal but, I would unbind my source upon loading the grid view and then rebind it prior to saving.

```
Dim myCurrencyManager As CurrencyManager = DirectCast(BindingContext(DataGridView1.DataSource), CurrencyManager)

myCurrencyManager.SuspendBinding()

myCurrencyManager.ResumeBinding()
```